# socket TCP: Why do I lose messages with scanf

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, scanf

I created a server and a client with c in Mac OS.
What they do is simple: the server sends messages and the client receives them.
However I don't know why but I always lose some of messages when I type more than one message with the help of `scanf`.
Here is the main codes:

```
// client
char msg[200];
while(1)
{
    if(read(sockclient, msg, sizeof(msg)) <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    printf("Message recu: %s\n", msg);
    bzero(msg, 200);
}


// server
while(1)
{
    lg=sizeof(coord_client);
    newsockfd=accept(sockserveur,(struct sockaddr*)&coord_client,(socklen_t *)&lg);
    char msg2[100];
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s",msg2);
        write(newsockfd,msg2,sizeof(msg2));
        printf("message envoye\n");
        bzero(msg2, sizeof(msg2));
    }
}
```

The problem is: if I type messages one by one, for example, `a<Enter>`, `b<Enter>`, everything is fine. But if I type more than one message at one time, I will always lose some of them. For example, if I type `a b c d<Enter>`, meaning that I want to send four messages: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, the client can always get three of them, `c` is miss. But the server does send four times because I get four `message envoye`.

**EDIT**
I checked the return value of the function `read` and I get something that I don't understand.
[image]

Please attention: when `read` returns `200` instead of `100`, the client will lose the following message.

Comment: what's the size of `BUF` ? you have 100 on one side and `BUF` on the other side.

Comment: You should check the return value of `read()`. It might not return the whole message size, it's allowed to return less than you specify.

Comment: also, no need to send the whole buffer: `strlen(msg2)+1` would be enough to send string + termination

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  BUF is 100.

Comment: @Barmar  I just checked the return value of `read()`. Most of cases it returns 100, for others it returns 200 then I will miss one message. Sending 100 is not good just like the other friend said, but I don't understand why `read` may get 200.

Comment: It can't return 200 if `sizeof(msg)` is 100.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If he sends only `strlen(msg2)+1`, he'll get out of sync when he reads all 100 bytes on the client.

Comment: @Barmar  It does give me one `200`, see the picture.

Comment: @Barmar  In fact my PC is Mac OS. The system might have some special stuff?

Comment: No, `read()` works the same on all systems. It can never return more than the `bufsize` parameter. You must be mistaken about what `sizeof(msg)` is.

Comment: I understand that. This means that `sizeof(msg)` on the client is at least 200.

Comment: @Barmar  yeah you are right. My original client code uses an array of 200 bytes whereas the server code uses an array of 100 bytes. I've reedited my question. So what's wrong with these two char arrays?

Comment: TCP doesn't preserve message boundaries, it's just a stream of bytes. So when the server sends two 100-byte messages, the server can read them both if it asks for 200 bytes.

Comment: It can also return *less* than you ask for. Instead of returning 100 bytes, it might return 50 bytes the first time, then 150 the next time.

Comment: @Barmar Could you make an answer for the question so that I can accept it?

Comment: The reason this happens when you put all the words on the same line is that the `scanf()` loop runs so quickly that both words are merged into a single TCP transmission by the kernel, and then the client is able to read it all at once.

Comment: There are no messages. TCP provides a stream. The number of sends does not necessarily need to match the number of receives. You want to take care of the number of bytes receives as returned by `recv()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's simple you read 200 bytes but you write 100 bytes. Sometime there are two write before the client read. So it read two message in a row.

```
char msg[101];
size_t i = 0;
ssize_t ret;
while (i < 100 && (ret = read(sockclient, msg + i, sizeof msg - i - 1)) <= 0)
{
  i += (size_t)ret;
}
if (i == 100) {
  msg[100] = '\0';
  printf("Message recu: %s\n", msg);
}
```

Comment: `i < 100` should be `i < 99`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @alk No because the server write 100 bytes and `i` must represent how many bytes we read. I didn't test :p.

Comment: You need to preserve space for the `0`-terminator. So the payload buffer in fact is buffer-size -1 .